# Evaluating a sum in $p$-th cyclotomic field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/p}\in\mathbb{C}$. Then we know that
$$
1+\zeta^a+\cdots + \zeta^{(p-1)a}=
\begin{cases}
p & \mbox{ if } a=0\\
0 & \mbox{ if } 1\le a<p
\end{cases}
$$
I came across forllowing expression, which I was not able to simplify - for $a,b\in \{0,1,\ldots, p-1\}$:

$$
1+\zeta^b + \zeta^{a+2b} + \zeta^{3a+3b} \cdots +  \zeta^{\binom{p-1}{2}a + (p-1)b} = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \zeta^{\binom{k}{2}a + kb}
$$
where $\binom{k}{2}=0$ for $k=0,1$.

Can one give some idea to simplify this expression?

Comment: Should be expressible in terms of Gauss sums, $\sum\zeta^{k^2}$.

Comment: The first displayed equation contains two typos. If you don't care, why should we?

Comment: @frans: Thank you very much for pointing it; I corrected it, is it okay now? (I was writing sum of $p$-many powers of an arbitrary $p$-th root of unity.)